# Azure Certificate Issued State

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I'm having an issue importing a new certificate to my App Service. When I try to import the certificate, the SSL Settings blade is replaced by a blank blade.
[image]

I'm not sure about the state of the certificate. I went through the Certificate Configuration steps, but I think the status of the certificate should be Ready not Issued.

Is there a way to assign the certificate to the App Service though PowerShell and bypass the Portal?

Comment: Is the SSL Settings blade still blank? I see your listed certificate is in the issued state. Usually, you can select it and upload the ASC certificate into your Web App directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use powershell [`New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding?view=azurermps-6.5.0) to bind a certificate to a Web App.

Bind a certificate existing on azure to a web app:

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName "ContosoResourceGroup" -WebAppName "ContosoWebApp" -Thumbprint "E3A38EBA60CAA1C162785A2E1C44A15AD450199C3" -Name "www.contoso.com"
```

Upload a certificate and bind it to a web app:

```
New-AzureRmWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName "ContosoResourceGroup" -WebAppName "ContosoWebApp" -CertificateFilePath "PathToPfxFile" -CertificatePassword "PlainTextPwd" -Name "www.contoso.com"
```

Comment: I wasn't able to try your solution. My client needed the service up ASAP, so I just purchased another and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help though.